# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets : 0 and 1 Predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am constructing confusion matrix based on prediction and ground truth. Previously, it worked fine on Python 3.5 but now Python 3.5 is unavailable. So I have to install python 3.7 for better working.

**Code**

```
predictions = gbm.predict(x_test)
predictions_classes = []
for i in predictions:
    prediction_class = np.argmax(i)
    predictions_classes.append(prediction_class)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions_classes, normalize=False)
print(cm)

tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()

recall = tp / (tp + fn)
precision = tp / (tp + fp)
accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tn + fp + fn + tp)
f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

print("Precision: ", 100 * precision, "%")
print("Recall: ", 100 * recall, "%")
print("F1 score ", 100 * f1, "%")
print("Accuracy: ", 100 * accuracy, "%")
```

**Trackback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/deepface/tests/Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 846, in <module>
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions_classes, normalize=False)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 276, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 91, in _check_targets
    "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets
```

Comment: So shall we assume that your targets are somewhat ternary and predictions are binary?

Comment: I just printed printed (y_test), print(predictions_classes) and i got two big matrix with 0 and 1 only.